# Select all breakpoint Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is there a way to select quickly all breakpoint in a specific class with Android Studio? Because it's uncomfortable to select them always with the mouse.

Comment: "Because it's uncomfortable". What? ha?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Breakpoints* window to manage all the breakpoints of your project. They can be grouped by package, file and enclosing type.

[image]

This action is also available in the *Run* menu